# Android: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory

Tags: android-ndk

I used the following...

> ~/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/Users/me/toolchain

Then I create the following code file...

```
int main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I tried ...

```
<toolchain>/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc test.c
```

I also tried

```
 <toolchain>/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=<toolchain>/sysroot test.c
```

Both come back...

```
 toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is there a way I can manually link this since something is obviously off?

Comment: I also tried export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld but again no dice.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To make it simpler, just set the sysroot:

```
<toolchain>/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ~/test.c -o ~/test --sysroot=/home/user/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
```

Comment: Thanks, --sysroot seems to be really mandatory thing for builds without that pesky ndk-build wrapper.

Comment: thank you very much @BlueSilver it takes lot of time to find out this one!

Answer (score 14):

> /arm-linux-androideabi-gcc test.c

You're missing `sysroot` in this one.

---

> /arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/sysroot test.c

This one, `sysroot` is wrong. It ahould be similar to:

```
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm
```

---

You also need to export LD (all the tools should be on path):

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:
/opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/:/opt/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/:/opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
$ echo $LD
arm-linux-androideabi-ld
```

You should probably export all the tools in the toolchain:

```
export CPP=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export AS=arm-linux-androideabi-as
export AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar
export RANLIB=arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
```

If you are working on an Autoconf project, add these:

```
$ echo $ANDROID_SYSROOT
/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok looking back I made my toolchain for Android-9 per the command...

> ~/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/tmp/my-toolchain

When I ran...

```
<install>/android-ndk-r8c$ find ./ -name crtbegin_dynamic*
.//platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-14/arch-mips/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-9/arch-mips/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
.//platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
```

As you can see my install of android-9 for some reason does not have this file. I rebuilt for android-14 and everything works fine. Anyone have an idea how this got like this? Bonehead file move on my part?

Comment: This is not the correct answer. BlueSilver's `--sysroot` is what was missing from the command line that caused the missing `crtbegin_dynamic.o`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me, I came to this question with the same issue, I am trying to build the gcc-4.8 toolchain in the NDK and ran into the same problem. The thing thats a bit different though about my situation is I am building on an Android device, which means I have the Bionic library `libc.so` and `libdl.so` in `/system/lib`. I was getting this error when configuring for `libgomp`:

```
toolchain-build/binutils-2.23/ld/ld-new: cannot find crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
toolchain-build/binutils-2.23/ld/ld-new: cannot find -lc
toolchain-build/binutils-2.23/ld/ld-new: cannot find -ldl
toolchain-build/binutils-2.23/ld/ld-new: cannot find crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
```

The Make file was setting a `-B` option to a particular directory `toolchain/gcc-4.8/gcc/` so I created symlinks from those two shared libs in `/system/lib` to `gcc-4.8/gcc`. Then I symlinked `crtbegin_dynamic.o` and `crtend_android.o` to the object files `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` that where compiled and installed into toolchain-build/prefix/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/`the`find` command can help you find them.

The commands I used to make the symlinks looked like this:

`ln -s ../../prefix/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/crtend.o crtend_android.o`

from within the `toolchian-build/gcc-4.8/gcc` directory, for me that worked because thats where the configuration was pointing to search with the `-B` option `make` passed to `xgcc`.

I hope that helps someone. Time to move on to `libatomic` ; )

Answer (score 0):

Also `-B` option set to a folder path with `crtbegin*.o` `crtend*.o` helps.