# Using clang for cross-compiling

Tags: android, clang, x86-64

I'm working on `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`. I'm using `clang` cross-compiler to generate executable for target `aosp_x86_64`.

**Command used**

```
clang -target x86_64-unknown-unknown-linux-android hello.c
```

**Ended up with error**

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I proceed ?

Comment: A similar issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795583/android-error-cannot-open-crtbegin-dynamic-o-no-such-file-or-directory). Do you have that file somewhere? Maybe some env var or cmdline arg is off/missing?

Comment: The location of crtbegin_dynamic.o is `/Libfuzzer/llvm/tools/clang/test/Driver/Inputs/basic_android_tree/sysroot/usr/lib` .

Comment: I did try  `clang --sysroot=/Libfuzzer/llvm/tools/clang/test/Driver/Inputs/basic_android_tree/sysroot/usr/lib  -target x86_64-unknown-linux-android hello.c -o hello.out` . Error is persistent.